# Script to check NFS share availability on Microsoft Servers

Tags: nfs

I am looking for a way to check NFS shares on a windows server to see if the share itself is active or inactive. I have been having issues with the shares becoming inactive even though they are being used and the NFS server services are still running. I haven't been able to find what I am looking for on Google and the NFS share checking scripts I have seen here are all checking the Unix side of the house. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use showexport and rpcinfo programms

```
$ rpcinfo -t netapp12 100003 3
 program 100003 version 3 ready and waiting
$
```

Probably they available for windows client as well.

Comment: Thank you for that info tigran, I will have to get with my windows team or see if I can get access to a server that has NFS running for me to look into. Makes me wish our NFS servers were linux based, would have made this much easier.

Edit - I want to upvote your answer sir, but I don't have the required rep :-(